# How to add multiple data in Codeigniter using loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys I just need a little help here about inserting information in my table using a loop.
I don’t know where’s my error.

Here’s my code: **In my INSERT model**

```
        $poid = $this->input->post('po_id');
        $cash_delivery = $this->input->post('cash_delivery');
        $cash_check = $this->input->post('cash_check');
        $bank_transfer = $this->input->post('bank_transfer');

        $itemname = $this->input->post('item'); // array of item name
        $quantity = $this->input->post('qty'); // array of quantity
        $price = $this->input->post('price'); //array of price
        $total = $this->input->post('total'); //array of total

       //CHECK IF TRANSACTION IS CHECKED

        $val_delivery = NULL;
        $val_check = NULL;
        $val_transfer = NULL;

        if(isset($_POST['cash_delivery'])){
            $val_delivery = 'Y';
        }else{
            $val_delivery = 'N';
        }

        if(isset($_POST['cash_check'])){
            $val_check = 'Y';
        }else{
            $val_check = 'N';
        }

        if(isset($_POST['bank_transfer'])){
            $val_transfer = 'Y';
        }else{
            $val_transfer = 'N';
        }

        $filtername = array_filter($itemname);
        $filterquantity = array_filter($quantity);
        $filterprice = array_filter($price);
        $filtertotal = array_filter($total);

        //INSERT ORDERS 

        for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($filtername); $x++){

            $orders = array(
                'poid' => null,
                'order_id' => $poid,
                'item_desc' => $filtername[$x],
                'item_qty' => $filterquantity[$x],
                'item_price' => $filtertotal[$x],
                'total' => $filtertotal[$x],
                'cash_on_delivery' => $val_delivery,
                'is_check' => $val_check,
                'bank_transfer' => $val_transfer,
                'transaction_date' => $dateorder
            );

            $this->db->insert('po_order',$orders); //Only first item (index[0]) is added
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($orders); //This will print my array values 'NO ERROR HERE'
            echo "<hr />";

        }

My database table design:

mysql> desc po_order;
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| poid             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order_id         | varchar(50)         | NO   | UNI | 0       |                |
| item_desc        | varchar(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_qty         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_price       | float(7,2) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| total            | float(7,2) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cash_on_delivery | enum('Y','N')       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_check         | enum('Y','N')       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bank_transfer    | enum('Y','N')       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_date | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**My problem is only the first item from the loop is added. I can't get the next items from the loop**.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, youre not getting the right value from $itemname = $this->input->post('item'); //array is expected to be return right?

try to see if it really does then.

and also for your for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($filtername); $x++){

what does sizeof($filtername) give you?

try

`die('for loop will iterate "'.sizeof($filtername).'" times');`

Comment: Ok about the $itemname = $this->input->post('item') I got the array containing my inputted data. I think to error in my array. About sizeof($filtername) it gave me for loop will iterate "2" times because in my array name i only inputted 2 fields.

Comment: I can see that youre over writing your databases auto incrementing primary key "poid" in your array property 'poid' => null, to null. You must be having a double primary key issue in your database. So, just remove it